# How to compose function and monad action in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I've just started learning Haskell.

I'm creating a program that find duplicate files. I have created the following functions:

```
hashFile :: (MonadIO m) => FilePath -> m (Digest MD5)
categorize :: Ord k => (a -> k) -> [a] -> Map.Map k [a]
```

And I want to compose them in a function that return

```
Map.Map (Digest MD5) [FilePath]
```

My questions are:

I can't find a way to deal with the IO monad to get what I want. So my questions are:

1. Is what I'm trying to do correct, or should the return type would
   really be `Map.Map (IO (Digest MD5)) [FilePath]`.
2. How do I compose these functions together to get the list of files grouped by hash?

Comment: 1. You have `FilePath -> IO (Digest MD5)`. Get a `FilePath -> IO (Digest MD5, FilePath)` // 2. Next, build up a `[IO (Digest MD5, FilePath)]` list // 3. Use the Traversable class to get a `IO [(Digest MD5, FilePath)]` // 4. Use Functor and `categorize` to get the desired `IO (Map (Digest MD5) [FilePath])`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's carefully compare the types of `hashFile` with the type of `categorize`, bearing in mind that we want to pass `hashFile` as an argument to `categorize`

```
hashFile ::             FilePath -> IO (Digest MD5)  -- I simplified the MonadIO constraint
categorize :: Ord k => (    a    ->        k       ) -> [a] -> M.Map k [a]
```

`categorize hashFile` won't type-check because GHC will try to match `k` with `IO (Digest MD5)`, but `IO` has no `Ord` instance. To put it another way, `IO (Digest MD5)` is useless as a key to a `Map`: what you need is `Digest MD5`s, not computations which will eventually produce `Digest MD5`s when you execute them.

What you really want to do is run all the `IO` computations and put their results (of type `Digest MD5`) into the `Map`. The resulting function would return `IO (Map (Digest MD5) FilePath)` - an `IO` computation which will return a `Map (Digest MD5) FilePath` when you run it.

---

The easiest way to do this is to adjust `categorize` to fit the type we need.

```
categorize :: (Applicative f, Ord k) => (a -> f k) -> [a] -> f (M.Map k a)
categorize f = fmap M.fromList . traverse (\x -> fmap (, x) (f x))
```

(I'm using [`TupleSections`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#tuple-sections).) First let's look at the type. Since `IO` is an instance of `Applicative`, `(a -> f k)` unifies with `FilePath -> IO (Digest MD5)` under the following constraints:

```
a ~ FilePath
f ~ IO
k ~ Digest MD5
```

So `categorize hashFile :: [FilePath] -> IO (M.Map (Digest MD5) FilePath)`, which is the type we want.

Now let's look at the implementation. [`traverse :: Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> [a] -> f [b]`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html#v:traverse)* (née [`mapM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:mapM)) takes an `Applicative` function, maps it over the list, and smashes the results together into a list. We're using it to turn each item into an `(result, item)` tuple. This'll produce an `f [(k, a)]` value. Then I `fmap` `M.fromList` over the result to produce `f (M.Map k a)`.

<sub>*Technically, `traverse` has the more general type of `(Applicative f, Traversable t) => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)`. I arrived at this version by taking `t ~ []`.</sub>

Because this implementation uses `M.fromList`, duplicate items will be thrown away. In practice, if you're not expecting any of the files to have the same contents, the MD5 hashes will be different so this won't be a problem. Exercise: how does this change if we want to keep duplicates?

Comment: @AndPos: "it helped me understand how to work with monads" but one of the important points here should be that you do *not* need a monad for this, an applicative functor suffices.

Comment: @Cactus I disagree that this is an important point. It is a point, but it is a subtle one and probably not important at all for 99% of applications, compared to the importance of understanding how to use the `Monad`-related interfaces to use `IO`, which needs to be done in 100% of useful applications.

Comment: @DanielWagner: I think monadic interfaces are overrepresented in beginner's materials so I never pass up an opportunity to advocate for applicative ones.